# "Laggy" cutscenes with my ps4

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

I've bought a ps4 with some games. But the "laggy" cutscene behavior occured only with two of them so far: Tomb Raider and Watch Dogs.

To be more precise, the initial cutscenes are "laggy": the one which lara gets hit on the head at the beach and the one which shows the bikers chasing Aiden (Tomb Raider and WD respectively)

But the games runs smoothly as they should. The only problem is with cutscenes. And i haven't reached a point on those games to see if the problem persists with anoter cutscenes.

What could be causing this? I know that the ps4 does a mandatory installation...could this be the hdd? Should i format it or something?

Comment: were you playing the games while you were still installing?

Comment: Well, as far as i know, no. When you put the disc, a small progress bar shows up...it means that the ps4 is installing right? If it is, then i always wait for it to finish, then i play the game. I've read about rebuild its database...should i do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known fault with both Tomb Raider and Watch Dogs](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2014/01/27/tomb-raider-definitive-edition-review-ps4/). Other games also suffer with cutscene frame rate issues on the PS4.

Including [this game released](http://www.seganerds.com/2014/11/20/alien-isolation-patch-addresses-cutscene-stuttering/) after Watch Dogs and Tomb Raider. Stuttering also affects the mini skill games prior to full games in FIFA 15. This is due to the CPU workload whilst loading the games next section.